# How show contents of wpf window in stack panel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

i want to show contents of window in wpf when click on button 
i think will use container controls like stake panel but doesn't work

```
private void RibbonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 w1 = new Window1();
        stkShow.Children.Add(w1);
    }
```

Comment: You cannot but you can create `UserControl` that is shown both in `Window` and `StackPanel`

Comment: Can you not just call `Show` or `ShowDialog` on window itself?

Comment: ok, how show the content of window in ribbon control when click on ribbon control button??

Comment: i want to use ribbon control such that mdi parent in c# Form

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the content of the window you want to use as child.
This worked for me.

```
private void RibbonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 Child = new Window1();
    StkPanelContent.Children.Clear();

    object content = Child.Content;
    Child.Content = null;
    Child.Close();
    this.stkShow.Children.Add(content as UIElement);
}
```

I hope it helps.